# Mutate changed, how to recode into new variable with excluded values defined as NA

Tags: dplyr

Mutate is no longer replacing only values defined, it is also carrying over other values that I didn't define. Is this something that changed in the package, or, what is going on? This is an issue because it's how I filtered out values outside of a Likert scale (representing "don't know" or "no opinion).

For example

q4 has values 1-9 but only 1-7 are relevant to the analysis of the scale in terms of generating descriptive statistics. I used to resolve this by coding into a new variable, L4, with only 1-7 options carried over. Like this:

```
mydata <- mutate(mydata, L4 = recode(q4, "1" = 1,
                                       "2" = 2,
                                       "3" = 3,
                                       "4" = 4,
                                       "5" = 5,
                                       "6" = 6,
                                       "7" = 7))
```

But now, R is including 8 and 9 in the new variable. It will recode the values defined, but also will carryover values not defined. **How can I define values > 7 as NA in a new variable?**

Here are some things I tried, they all failed for various reasons.

```
mydata <- mutate(mydata, L4 = recode(q4, is.na(.x >= 7.5 )))
mydata <- mutate(mydata, L4 = na_if(.x, q4 >= 7.5))
mydata <- mutate(mydata, L4 ~replace_na(q4, (q4 >= 7.7))
  across(c(q4,q7:q14v4,q19), ~replace_na(.x, mean(.x[.x<=7], na.rm=TRUE))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydata <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(L4 = recode(
    q4, "1" = 1,
    "2" = 2,
    "3" = 3,
    "4" = 4,
    "5" = 5,
    "6" = 6,
    "7" = 7, 
    .default = NA_real_
  ))
```

Comment: Thank you! I had never encountered this issue before and use mutate in this manner a lot. Is there something that changed, or how did that setting get altered? Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Not sure if anything changed, but it should be noted in the change log if it was: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html.  I had never actually used `recode` so I pulled up the help document and just saw the argument.